# Lebesgue measure of a set containing numbers without zero in their decimal expansion.

Tags: measure-theory

Let A  ⊆ [0,1] be the set of real numbers which do not have zero in their decimal expansion.
Can someone give me a hint that helps me compute the Lebesgue measure of this subset?

I think that I have to work with the fact that every rational number has 0 in its decimal expansion or can be considered as if it has one (since some of you correctly said to me that 1/3 is a rational number without 0 in its decimal expansion) because the set of rational number has Lebesgue measure zero, hence A does not contain the set of rational number.

Comment: Isn't $A=\{1\}$ ? Or you are just looking at the portion of the decimal expansion that comes after the point

Comment: In the second case, it is easier to compute $A^c$ instead

Comment: To correct something you wrote, $0.3333\ldots = \frac{1}{3}$ is a rational number which doesn't have a zero after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

What is the measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ that don't have $0$ as their first decimal? In their first two decimals? Their first three? And in their first $n$ decimals?

Comment: I'm trying to prove by induction that this set has measure (9/10)^n, but I'm not going further, anyway thank for the hint. I'll keep on working.

Comment: @Ale It might help to think of it as a modified construction of the Cantor set, where the bottom tenth of each interval is removed in each iteration rather than the middle third.